# Generating RestClientException error in mockito unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I am trying to validate a restclientexception error. My code is below and help would be appreciated. This is from my test class:`

`

```
@Test
void test_update_customer_in_ath0_server_error(){
    //given
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
    doReturn(responseEntity)
            .when(restTemplate).exchange(any(), eq(HttpMethod.PATCH), any(HttpEntity.class), (Class<String>)any());


    idpFacadeClient.updateCustomerFirstNameInIdp(updateRecordsDto);

    //then
    verify(restTemplate).exchange(any(), eq(HttpMethod.PATCH), argThat(this::verifyUpdatedCustomerBody), (Class<String>)any());
}
```

This is from my injectMock class

`

```
try {
    response = restTemplate.exchange(URI.create(idpFacadeUpdateUrl), HttpMethod.PATCH, entity,  String.class);
    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        log.info("customer first name update success {} with status {}", customerUpdateRecordsDto.getFirstName(), response.getStatusCode());
    }else {
        log.error("Customer first name update failed in IDP for {} with status {}", customerUpdateRecordsDto.getFirstName(), response.getStatusCode());
    }
} catch (RestClientException e) {
    throw new RestClientException("Idp facade API error for user first name " + customerUpdateRecordsDto.getFirstName(), e);
}
```

`

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: SonarQube shows lines 8 - 10 of the second code as not tested. I want a scenario where I can throw a RestClientException and assert it. @Knittl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your mock throw an exception when the `exchange` method is called:

```
doThrow(new RestClientException())
            .when(restTemplate).exchange(any(), eq(HttpMethod.PATCH), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(String.class));
```

And then verify the new exception thrown in the catchblock with `assertThrows` or `assertThatCode(…).hasMessageContaining(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with JUnit5, try replacing the last line with something like this:

```
assertThrows(RestClientException.class, () -> idpFacadeClient.updateCustomerFirstNameInIdp(updateRecordsDto));
```

In JUnit4 the @Test annotation provides a parameter to specify an expected exception for the test.

Comment: I've tried but I got this error: 
java.lang.AssertionError: expected org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstood the goal. What is happening here is that the verify method arguments are not matching the real ones. Try two things: 1- Check that verifyUpdatedCustomerBody is matching the body. 2- Replace (Class<String>)any() by any(String.class)

Comment: This answer was very helpful as well. It literally a combination of both answers. Thank you.